# Convert char to byte

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert char array to byte. But I am getting the below error:

> Cannot implicitly convert int to byte

```
public byte[] asciiToDecConversion(char[] asciiCharArray)
{
    byte[] decimalArray = new byte[10];
    const byte asciiFormat = 32;

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        decimalArray[j] = (Convert.ToByte(asciiCharArray[j]) - asciiFormat);
    }

    return decimalArray;
}
```

Comment: @sunshine, you had several valid answers, so you should mark one as accepted so your post does not appear unanswered, and also you give credit to those who took the time to try to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast to byte:

```
decimalArray[j] = (byte) (Convert.ToByte(asciiCharArray[j]) - asciiFormat);
```

Comment: Why `Convert.ToByte` for one cast and a direct cast for the other? Actually, that `Convert.ToByte` is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cast it directly:

```
decimalArray[j] = (byte)(asciiCharArray[j] - asciiFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple as this:

```
char[] charArray = "your string".ToCharArray(); // For example.
byte[] byteArray = charArray.Select(c => (byte)(c - 32)).ToArray();
```

Bear in mind that you code will fail if `asciiCharArray` has less than 10 elements.